# using queries generated by name with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to write a query in Spring Boot, I have the query written like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypoxz.png)
, but when I search for the vehicle objects by year by doing http://localhost:8080/vehicles?year=(year) it returns to me all of the vehicle objects instead of only ones that match the year.

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow, please take the time to read through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask where it says `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://localhost:8080/vehicles?year=2001

If still error try your query in sql command, i think any mistake in your query or check again in your controller file